# Почему не работают возможности 3D в Photoshop CC?

Tags: photoshop

Недавно боролся с проблемой зависания приложений, использующих OpenCL. Проблема решилась установкой более старой версии драйвера для Intel HD Graphics 4600. Теперь появилась проблема с невозможностью Фотошопа использовать возможности 3D. Также неактивны некоторые фильтры. 
 Все драйвера только что обновил, проблема не исчезла. Фотошоп переустановил. Использование Graphic Card Acceleation и все галочки в ней стоят

Answer (score 1):

Проблема для Фотошопа решена установкой в Панели управления Nvidia всех разрешений для photoshop.exe